# Retrofit login using POST android

Tags: android, post, retrofit

I'm trying to use the login API from my server via Retrofit but seems that I cannot make this right. Right now I'm getting this in logCat `No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)` for using this code:

Api call:
`http://www.myapi.com/v1/index.php/login` with the parameters `email` and `password`

```
//this is the interface:
 @POST("/login")
    void login( String email,String password, Callback<BaseMO> callback);

//this is the api call
     restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(ServerParams.API_URL)
                    .build();
    ServerEndpoints apiService =
                            restAdapter.create(ServerEndpoints.class);
                    apiService.login("meil@gmail.com", "000000", new Callback<BaseMO>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(BaseMO baseMO, Response response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Success " + response.getReason() + " | " + baseMO.getMessage());

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });
```

Can someone help me make this right. Thanks!

Comment: void login( @Query("email") String email,@Query("password") String password, Callback<BaseMO> callback); try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a more carefull reading of the docs I've found my answer, I'll post it here so if someone in the future has this or similar problem.
The interface should be defined as:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/login")
    void login(@Field("email") String email,@Field("password")String password, Callback<BaseMO> callback);
```